# Convert Single line of Text to Lookup type after importing data from Excel file

Tags: excel-services, import

I imported the data from excel file, but some column data type I need to change from single line of text to Lookup value. How to do this? I am using SharePoint 2013

Answer (score 1):

I guess there is no out of the box way of doing this. You could do it by powershell:
1. Create a new list column (lookup)
2. Iterate trough your list, check for the value in the old column and check for values in the list you want to make the lookup from.
3. Write matches to new list column

Some powershell reference:
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/anavijai/add-and-modify-the-existing-site-column-in-sharepoint-2010-using-powershell/